# GCP google instance group

Tags: google-compute-engine, distributed-computing, distributed, multiple-instances, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on an architecture to deploy my webapp. I would like to use Google Managed Instance Groups because I have some strict requirements. I was wondering:

- which is the best Web container to be deployed in a distributed environment?
- I'm familiar with Tomcat, it's Tomcat OK to be deployed in an instance group?
- my Webapp running on tomcat will generate logs that will be stored in the current machine hosting tomcat. How should I handle distributed application logs.

I don't want to lose information and I would like to have a single view of all log of my webapp even if distributed, Is it that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used tomcat in GCP for over a year and it has worked without problems with the load balancer. To solve the issue of the logs you must use an agent to save the logs in stackdriver https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/service/agent-logs